# Как вставить текст после родителя определённого кол-ва символов?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Уже долго не могу разобраться..
У меня есть блок, в котором есть текст (множество абзацев, где каждый в своём теге).
Как мне вставить после родителя 20 символа текст (и можно ли реализовать сие без углубления в range)?

Например:

```
<p id="art1">Привет приятель</p><p id="art2">Пока мой друг</p>
```

здесь,  20-ым символом является К (поКа), и как мне на основе этого сделать так, чтобы я получил родителя, а значит

с id равным art2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перебираете элементы, суммируете длины их текстового содержимого:

```js
const text = 'hello, world!!';
const max = 20;
let len = 0;

for (const p of document.querySelectorAll('p')) {
  len += p.textContent.length;
  if (len >= max) {
    p.insertAdjacentText('afterend', text);
    break;
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="art1">Привет приятель</p>
<p id="art2">Пока мой друг</p>
```

[источник](https://qna.habr.com/q/787711)